# Login and logout issues in an Android app

Tags: android, authentication, logout

I'm stuck with one issue... So I build app, which, after login shows user information in MainActivity (I did that with Intent). Then I starts the app, I have to login with PIN Code. First time everything is fine. But if I click Logout button in mainActivity, I come back to LoginActivity and if I try to Login again, I don't get user information anymore. Only null values from sessionManager. I hope you understand my problem. I think the problem is here:

```
/** **SessionManager.java**
 * Get stored session data
* */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // user userName
    user.put(KEY_USER_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_USER_NAME, null));

    // user workerGid
    user.put(KEY_WORKER_GID, pref.getString(KEY_WORKER_GID, null));

    // user firstName
    user.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_FIRST_NAME, null));

    // user lastName
    user.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_LAST_NAME, null));

    // user mechGid
    user.put(KEY_MECH_GID, pref.getString(KEY_MECH_GID, null));

    // user transportName
    user.put(KEY_TRANSPORT_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_TRANSPORT_NAME, null));

    // return user
    return user;
}


 //Clear session details

public void logoutUser(){
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

}

//MapActivity: // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    // First Name
    String firsName = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_FIRST_NAME);

    // Last Name
    String lastName = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_LAST_NAME);

    // Transport Name
    String transportName = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_TRANSPORT_NAME);

    TextView transport_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.transport);
    transport_name.setText(transportName);

    TextView nameLastname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
    nameLastname.setText(firsName + lastName);

    View logoutButton = findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
    View.OnClickListener button_logout = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(session.isLoggedIn())
                session.logoutUser();
            Intent in = new Intent(MapActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
    };
    logoutButton.setOnClickListener(button_logout)
```

Comment: where do you set your shared preferences

Comment: show complete code

Comment: Here is all my SessionManager https://paste.ofcode.org/39hbbzhuf4dJk3uxd5dgif2

Comment: Here is all my MainActivity https://paste.ofcode.org/76qXgrAZNjkpMmMvR3nFQY
Here is LoginActivity:
https://paste.ofcode.org/3aknXY3hbV4mujFpFCzwp6y

Comment: I dont understand your problem, After logout your are clearing user session, then everything will be null from session manager. What is the issue

Comment: yes, after logout everything is cleared. But if I login again, I dont get the values, here is the problem

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment above by @Suranhi Singh you are clearing your preferences, in this case is your user session. When you open your app again, it creates a new ,and empty, instance of SessionManager which overwrites the previous.

I suggest using a different tag to save the info you want to persist separate from the SessionManager. Dont use SessionManager for the data you want to be saved.